# Perl cannot get content from html page, while the page has all the necessary tags

Tags: python, html, perl, web-crawler

I'm trying to build a Redfin api, where I'm trying to get the content using LWP::Simple, for this link

[Redfin Link](http://www.redfin.com/CA/San-Jose/947-Hummingbird-Dr-95125/home/1309375#schools)

The content I get in a result, doesnot have the deails of the school. What I want is a "Willow Glen Middle School" and I have another API, that would take the input of this text and return with an exact API score.

I tried the same thing using Python, still the same result, below I'm dumping a code in perl. Whichever works, I'll take it.

It just has a simple code now :

```
use LWP::Simple;

$content = get("https://www.redfin.com/CA/San-Jose/947-Hummingbird-Dr-95125/home/1309375#schools");

print "Call API" if($content =~ /Willow Glen Middle School/);
```

Comment: Can we assume you have permission to do this? https://www.redfin.com/about/terms-of-use - F. Webscraping of Listing & Property Data Is Not Allowed Crawling the Redfin.com and network sites is allowed for inclusion in web search engine results only. Webscraping, downloading or webcrawling of any property or other data for inclusion in another real estate search site, content aggregator, or any other purpose is strictly forbidden without prior written consent from Redfin.

Comment: @Oesor It's for my personal use though

Comment: works fine using python

Comment: Re. "It's for my personal use" I think the key phrase is "or any other purpose."

Comment: I agree, to be more clear, the API scores are off, and I want an easy way to get the school to name which is served in that area and it can look up in an excel sheet which has a correct API. Now, using python as @PadraicCunningham shows the same result in the requests module of python as does Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the result for school is because there is no result of school. The content of the page is populated using javascript, whereas your `get` method gives `HTML` without processing with javascript. You need to use something like `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` to get your example to work. However note that it will be much slower that `LWP`.

Here is a sample code

```
#use LWP::Simple;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->get("https://www.redfin.com/CA/San-Jose/947-Hummingbird-Dr-95125/home/1309375#schools");
#print $mech->content;

if($mech->content=~/Willow Glen Middle School/){
        print "ya\n";
}
```